# The device stops outputting digital video when Raspberry Pi Pico is connected to a logic analyzer

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm working on a project where I connect a Raspberry Pi Pico to a game console. I noticed something weird which I can't figure out on my own. When I connect a logic analyzer to the Pico, the console stops displaying video over digital output (composite analog still works).

I narrowed down the issue and it's enough to just connect ground probe from the logic analyzer. The logic analyzer is connected to my PC with a USB cable. The issue doesn't happen if I connect the logic analyzer to a USB power supply. It looks like my PC is messing it up.

Can someone explain to me what's happening here? Is it a ground loop issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: We would not know whether or not it is a ground loop issue, because you have not mentioned how your ground wiring, or any other wiring, is wired. At least provide some info to work on.

Comment: Pico is soldered to an adapter board that connects through the memory card slot to PlayStation console. I'm connecting logic analyzer ground probe to any GND point on Pico board and it's enough to mess up digital video output. I also noticed the same thing happens when Pico is connected to the PC using USB Cable and the logic analyzer is not connected at all.

Comment: And how are your PCs and game consoles connected together, like, does the PC or any other device have mains plug with an earth prong but not connected to earthed socket, or are all mains plugs two-prong? That is needed to determine if you have a ground loop or some other problem.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Okay so the console uses 2 prong plug and it's connected to the same wall outlet as the PC. The computer uses 3 prong plug.

Comment: Are you connecting the ground probe to something that isn't ground?

Comment: If the computer has a 3 prong grounded plug, is it connected to a matching grounded outlet?

Comment: Many power supply designs have a capacitor between the DC output ground and the mains AC input. It's for ex. 100 nF, so the mains AC leak is not lethal, but it can generate bad noise gathering ground loops and burn interface circuits when signal cable connectors are plugged in or out. The capacitor is there because it reduces harmful radio noise emissions which otherwise would make the device illegal to be used. If one uses a device with grounded AC plug from a non-grounded outlet he creates that leak by himself. His device GND has generally 50% of the mains AC voltage.